# How to go back to navigate the previous screen without re rendering any function react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo-client, mutation

Here on button click event I am uploading some data in server . I am using mutation for this . And after the response I have to navigate to previous screen and I don't want to refresh the page or re-render the any life cycle methods of the screen where i am directing .
I have used this.props.navigation.navigate("pagename") ,but by using this some function is getting call .
So I have used "this.props.navigation.goBack()" ,but again same .
I have to go back to previous screen after submitting request to server.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View } from 'native-base';
    import {withApollo } from 'react-apollo';
    import gql from 'graphql-tag';
    import _ from 'lodash';
    import OverlaySpinner from '../ui/overlaySpinner';
    import AddNoteSection from '../../components/tabs/requestTab/AddNoteSection';
    import { handleErrors } from '../../services';


    class AddNoteSectionContainer extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            categoryList: [],
            isOpenClose: false,
            notes: "",
            notesResponse:[]
          };
        }

        addNoteChange = (event) => {
            this.setState({
              notes: event
            }, () => {
            });
          };

        statusTextModification = (currentstatus) => {
          var status ="";
         if (currentstatus === "Pending"){
           status = "P"
         }else if(currentstatus === "Close"){
          status = "C"
         }else{
          status = "A"
         }
         return status;
        } 

        OnButtonClick = async (data) => {
          var status = "";
          const{navigation}=this.props;
          const{workFlowDetails,troubleTicketDetails} =  
      navigation.state.params.ticketDetailsInfo;
          const workAgent_ID = workFlowDetails.currentNextActivity;

          const currentStepPosition = workAgent_ID.filter((item) => {
            return item._activityStatus === "I"
              });
           const workAgentID = currentStepPosition.map(currentStepPosition => {
            return currentStepPosition._workAgent;
               });
            let workAgent_id=workAgentID[0];
               console.log("Props for note  notes",workAgent_id);

              if (navigation.state.params.currentStatus === "Pending"){
                status = "P"
              }else if(navigation.state.params.currentStatus === "Close"){
               status = "C"
              }else{
               status = "A"
              }

          const mutationObj = `
            mutation createIncidentNote{
              createIncidentNote(
                input:{
                  status: "${status}",
                  incidentInitiator: "${data}",
                  notes: "${this.state.notes}",
                  userId: "${troubleTicketDetails.LoggedBy}",
                  workAgentID: "${workAgent_id}", 
                  referenceNumber: "${navigation.state.params.referenceNumber}",

                }){
                  REQUEST_STATUS
                  ABILLITY_REF_NUM
                  SUCCESS_MESG_LANG_1
                  SUCCESS_MESG_LANG_2
              }
            }
          `;
          try {
            const { data } = await this.props.client.mutate({
              mutation: gql(mutationObj)
            });
            // Here below is the code  I am using . 
            this.props.navigation.goBack()

          } catch (e) {
            handleErrors(e, this.props.navigation);
            console.log('Error in Adding note', e);
          }
        };

    render(){
       return(
          <View>
             <AddNoteSection
           {...this.props}
           addNoteChange={(text) => this.addNoteChange(text)}
           OnButtonClick={(data) => this.OnButtonClick(data)}
           />
             {/* {<OverlaySpinner color="#00678F" />}  */}
          </View>
       )
    }
    }
        export default withApollo(AddNoteSectionContainer);
```

Comment: You don't want to render anything but you want the screen to change?

Comment: yes............

Comment: Okay, then no, it's impossible.

Comment: but when we do back button left side in header ,it just navigate to back screen what we had open recent ,but when we use props.navigation.navigate that is something different

Comment: Navigate is not rendered again, so the rendering is push again. Check through the console.